# How to make navbar stay visible, after href?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, href, navbar

I have a bootsrap navbar, and every menu elements of it has a href attribute, to navigate through pages. When I click on, one of the elements the navbar disappears, of course because I left the page which contained it. But how can I do it dinamically? One always visible navbar fixed top, and every html page( navbar element) stay on the page where the navbar is.(without a database)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="topmenu">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

  <li class="dropdown active">
    <a href="us.html" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#one">US</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="services.html" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#two">SERVICES</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="wwu.html" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#three">WORK WITH US</a>
  </li>  
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="en.html" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#four">EN</a>
  </li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: can you please post your code here

Comment: if you use php you can make a file specifically for your navbar, something like `navbar.php`. Then when ever you want to use your navbar on that page you would write `require_once('navbar.php)`

Comment: Not a bad idea, I"m going to try it!

Comment: Didn't work properly :(

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like this:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <a href="javascript:goto('http://google.com')">Google</a>
    ...
</div>
<iframe id="frame" width="100%" height="100%">Update Browser!</iframe>
<script>
  function goto(url){
    document.getElementById("frame").src=url;
  }
</script>
```

This will load the clicked link into the iframe. The page stays the same, so the navbar is still visible. You could also redirect all link cicks to end up into the iframe:

```
    <div id="navbar">
    <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
    ...
</div>
<iframe id="frame" width="100%" height="100%">Update Browser!</iframe>
<script>
  window.onload=function (){
      [...document.getElementsByTagName("a")].forEach(function(a){
         a.onclick=function(e){
            e.preventDefault();//the redirect
           document.getElementById("frame").src=this.href;
         }
      });
  };
</script>
```

Or if you like the jquery.load:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
    ...
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").each(function(){
     this.on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#content").load(this.href);
      });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I need. I should do it without an iframe. I'd need a solution like JQuery partial page load(refresh), but with files.